# How can I optimize my query it is taking too much time in mysql

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

Here I'm fetching data using mysql queries but it is taking time around 10 seconds 20 seconds so on ,even though all the columns are indexed. so I'm new to the optimization so please help me

```
SELECT a.cname, 
       (SELECT status_name 
        FROM   persontype_status 
        WHERE  status = a.p3_status 
        LIMIT  1)                                                 AS 
       company_status_psp3, 
       a.curl, 
       a.cid, 
       a.pid, 
       a.addedbyuser, 
       a.no_of_emp, 
       ( CASE 
           WHEN a.lead_status > 0 
                AND ( a.status = 0 
                       OR a.status > 0 ) THEN (SELECT ( Max(Date(dateadded)) ) 
                                               FROM   d3_info 
                                               WHERE  cid = a.cid 
                                               GROUP  BY cid) 
           WHEN ( a.status > 0 
                  AND a.lead_status = 0 ) THEN (SELECT ( Min(Date(dateadded)) ) 
                                                FROM   sperson_info 
                                                WHERE  cid = a.cid 
                                                GROUP  BY cid) 
           ELSE 0 
         end )                                                    AS date_new, 
       a.rank, 
       a.lead_status, 
       a.status, 
       a.magid, 
       (SELECT pname 
        FROM   personinfo 
        WHERE  pid = a.pid)                                       AS pname, 
       p1_status, 
       Count(c.email_id)                                          AS total_mail, 
       Count(IF(s.mail_type IN( 'First Mail', 'Reminder 1' ) 
                AND c.person_type = 'P1' 
                AND d.send_status = 1, c.email_id, NULL))         AS t_p1, 
       Count(IF(s.mail_type IN( 'First Mail', 'Reminder 1' ) 
                AND c.person_type = 'P2' 
                AND d.send_status = 1, c.email_id, NULL))         AS t_p2, 
       Count(IF(( s.mail_type IN( 'First Mail', 'Reminder 1' ) 
                  AND c.person_type = 'P3' 
                  AND d.send_status = 1 ), c.email_id, NULL))     AS t_p3, 
       Count(DISTINCT IF(c.person_type = 'P3' 
                         AND c.email_id != '', c.email_id, NULL)) AS t_p3_e, 
       Count(IF(( s.mail_type IN( 'First Mail', 'Reminder 1' ) 
                  AND c.person_type = 'P4' 
                  AND d.send_status = 1 ), c.email_id, NULL))     AS t_p4, 
       Count(DISTINCT IF(c.person_type = 'P4' 
                         AND c.email_id != '', c.email_id, NULL)) AS t_p4_e, 
       Count(IF(( s.mail_type IN( 'First Mail', 'Reminder 1' ) 
                  AND c.person_type = 'P5' 
                  AND d.send_status = 1 ), c.email_id, NULL))     AS t_p5, 
       Count(DISTINCT IF(c.person_type = 'P5' 
                         AND c.email_id != '', c.email_id, NULL)) AS t_p5_e, 
       Count(IF(( s.mail_type IN( 'First Mail', 'Reminder 1' ) 
                  AND c.person_type = 'P6' 
                  AND d.send_status = 1 ), c.email_id, NULL))     AS t_p6, 
       Count(DISTINCT IF(c.person_type = 'P6' 
                         AND c.email_id != '', c.email_id, NULL)) AS t_p6_e, 
       Count(IF(( s.mail_type IN( 'First Mail', 'Reminder 1' ) 
                  AND c.person_type = 'P7' 
                  AND d.send_status = 1 ), c.email_id, NULL))     AS t_p7, 
       Count(DISTINCT IF(c.person_type = 'P7' 
                         AND c.email_id != '', c.email_id, NULL)) AS t_p7_e, 
       Count(IF(( s.mail_type IN( 'First Mail', 'Reminder 1' ) 
                  AND c.person_type = 'P8' 
                  AND d.send_status = 1 ), c.email_id, NULL))     AS t_p8, 
       Count(DISTINCT IF(c.person_type = 'P8' 
                         AND c.email_id != '', c.email_id, NULL)) AS t_p8_e  FROM   mperson_companies a 
       INNER JOIN aperson_detail c 
               ON a.cid = c.cid 
                  AND a.pid = c.pid 
       LEFT JOIN compose d 
              ON c.email_id = d.receiver_email 
                 AND c.pid = d.pid 
       LEFT JOIN session_person s 
              ON d.session_id = s.session_id  WHERE  a.lead_status = 0 
       AND a.flag != 'q' 
       AND a.approval != 5 
       AND a.pid = 2832 
       AND a.rank > 1 
       AND c.email_id != ''  GROUP  BY a.cid  HAVING t_p1 = 2 
       AND t_p2 = 2 
       AND IF(t_p3_e = 1, t_p3 = 2, 1 = 1) 
       AND IF(t_p4_e = 1, t_p4 = 2, 1 = 1) 
       AND IF(t_p5_e = 1, t_p5 = 2, 1 = 1) 
       AND IF(t_p6_e = 1, t_p6 = 2, 1 = 1) 
       AND IF(t_p7_e = 1, t_p7 = 2, 1 = 1) 
       AND IF(t_p8_e = 1, t_p8 = 2, 1 = 1)  ORDER  BY date_new DESC;
```

Comment: `EXPLAIN` can help you solve your problem [read this](https://www.eversql.com/mysql-explain-example-explaining-mysql-explain-using-stackoverflow-data/)

Comment: yaa I got that information but actually how can I reduce my code  there are so many conditions there ,so can I reduce those conditions?

Comment: Also consider a rewrite and use deliverd tables where you Count so you dont need to have Count distinct

Answer (score 0):

Need to see `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT`.

Meanwhile, this

```
    WHERE  a.lead_status = 0
      AND  a.flag != 'q'
      AND  a.approval != 5
      AND  a.pid = 2832
      AND  a.rank > 1
      AND  c.email_id != ''
```

begs for

```
INDEX(lead_status, pid,   -- in either order
      flag, approval,     -- in either order
      rank)               -- last
```

and this
                  SELECT  ( Min(Date(dateadded)) )
                        FROM  sperson_info
                        WHERE  cid = a.cid
                        GROUP BY  cid)

does not need to include `GROUP BY cid`, since it will return only the one item.

And

```
( a.status = 0  OR  a.status > 0 )
```

can be simply

```
a.status >= 0
```

But, what values are there for `status`?  Inequalities are sometimes less efficient than equalities.

And this

```
       Count(IF(s.mail_type IN( 'First Mail', 'Reminder 1' )
                      AND  c.person_type = 'P2'
                AND  d.send_status = 1, c.email_id, NULL)
                     )
```

can be shortened to

```
       SUM(   s.mail_type IN( 'First Mail', 'Reminder 1' )
         AND  c.person_type = 'P2'
         AND  d.send_status = 1 )
```

There may be more suggestions; this could take a few iterations.